# netsnmp_gethostbyname_v4 behavior

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

res = netsnmp_gethostbyname_v4('0.0.0.0', pdu_in_addr_t);

res = ???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code of netsnmp_gethostbyname_v4()](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/system_8c_source.html), that function returns an integer. More specifically it returns a status code which is `0` on success and `-1` or failure.